# how to auto turn only the first letter of chapter into uppercase?

Tags: fonts, macros

- I want to auto turn only the first letter of chapter, section and subsection into uppercase.

Can this solve that?

```
\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\scshape}{\thesection}{1em}{}
```

- Second point: How can I put the first letter of a paragraph in bold uppercase?

**Edit:**
found `\makefirstuc` from package `mfirstuc` how can i use it in a macro? like above

Comment: Rather than plain uppercase, you could use the [`lettrine` package](https://www.ctan.org/pkg/lettrine) to enhance your presentation of the firs letter of each paragraph / chapter / section / subsection.

Comment: not sure what letterine does but i am not looking for an exgerated design and big font

Comment: by the way any suggestions to well tag this question?

Comment: Do you mean the first letter of the section heading or (as lettrine would do) the first letter of the content of the section. either way why not just enter it as uppercase in the source?

Comment: sometimes i forget to do it so i want to put some macros to do that auto for me to be sure

Comment: You could append `\MakeUppercase` to `\normalfont\scshape`.  If `titlesec` does not brace the argument to chapter it should capitalise the first token.

Comment: @HenriMenke \MakeUppercase returns an error

Comment: @HenriMenke It _does_ brace the parameter of course, exactly so that you can use this in a reasonable way.

Comment: @HenriMenke i didnt follow what you meant can you write it ?

Comment: @guest00 If you prepare a [minimal working example (MWE)](http://meta.tex.stackexchange.com/q/228) I will be happy to help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might do like the following:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}

\usepackage{mfirstuc}
\usepackage{titlesec}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\scshape}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {\makefirstuc}

\begin{document}

\section{Capital}

\section{capital}

%\section{équipe}

\end{document}
```

but, as soon as the third `\section` command is uncommented, you'll get an error. Not when you use XeLaTeX or LuaLaTeX, though.

In case you need accented letters in `pdflatex`, you could do in a more complicated fashion:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{titlesec}
\usepackage{xparse}

\titleformat{\section}
  {\normalfont\scshape}
  {\thesection}
  {1em}
  {}

\let\originalsection\section
\makeatletter
\RenewDocumentCommand{\section}{som}{%
  \protected@edef\section@opt{\MakeFirstUppercase#2\MakeFirstUppercase}%
  \protected@edef\section@mand{\MakeFirstUppercase#3\MakeFirstUppercase}%
  \IfBooleanTF{#1}
    {\originalsection*{\section@mand}}
    {\IfNoValueTF{#2}
      {\originalsection{\section@mand}}
      {\originalsection[\section@opt]{\section@mand}}%
    }%
}
\protected\def\MakeFirstUppercase#1#2\MakeFirstUppercase{%
  \ifx#1\IeC
    \MakeUppercase#2%
  \else
    \MakeUppercase#1#2%
  \fi
}
\makeatother


\begin{document}

\section{Capital}

\section{capital}

\section{équipe}

\section{Équipe}

\end{document}
```

[image]

All in all, it's ***much*** better to rely on correct typing.

Comment: The error could be circumvented by using a UTF-8 engine, as `é` is a single token there.

Comment: why when i remove `{\normalfont\scshape}` i get another error in fact i only want to turn uppercase i dont want to change fontsize it was only a bad example from me to explain

Comment: @guest00 You can replace `{\normalfont\scshape}` with `{}` or `{\normalfont\large}` or whatever. If you remove all of it (don't even leave `{}`), then you aren't passing the correct number of arguments, so you'll get an error.

Comment: @guest00 Sorry, but I answered your question.

Comment: thanks  egreg even it's too complicated, @crf when i remove and let only {} it seems that the font change not like the one when i use section without any modification

Comment: @egreg how can you build such code :) ?